# List out of custom web parts deployed in all site pages using power shell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

Need some help to list out all custom web parts deployed in all sites pages in an site collection using power shell. Any help appreciated. am able to list out all web parts in all site pages 
Custom Web parts ...

Answer (score 0):

[Listing web parts used on all site pages using Powershell](https://myspworld.wordpress.com/2012/03/13/listing-web-parts-used-on-all-site-pages-using-powershell/)

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing")

function ListWebParts($web) {
if ([Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::IsPublishingWeb($web))
{
$webPublish = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)
$pages = $webPublish.GetPublishingPages()

foreach($page in $pages)
{
$manager = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($page.Url, [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
$webCollection = $manager.WebParts
if($webCollection.Count -ne 0)
{
for($i =0;$i -lt $webCollection.Count; $i++)
{
$sw.writeline($web.url + "/" + $page.url + ";" + $webCollection[$i].GetType().Name + ";" +    $webCollection[$i].Title)
}
}
}
}
}

function LoadSPSite()
{
$siteURL = "http://YOUR SITE'S URL"
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteURL)

foreach($web in $site.allwebs)
{
write-output $web.Title
ListWebParts($web)
}
$site.Dispose()
}

$sw = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "PATH TO LOG FILE"
$sw.writeline("Page URL;Web Part Type;Web Part Title")
LoadSPSite
$sw.close()
```